# Unable to add basemap to new map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-online-basemaps

I tapped on the down arrow closer to the Add Data bottom but the Add Basemap that appeared could not be selected.

Comment: Are you using ArcMap?  What version?

Comment: Are you connected to ArcGIS Online?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this ? This might be your reason why you are not getting any basemap [Why is Add Basemap grayed out in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116956/why-is-add-basemap-grayed-out-in-arcmap)